# Regex to find (and replace) a foreign key in SQL script

Tags: regex, awk, sed

I have an sql script with table creation scripts for multiple tables. I need a script (sed) to update a foreign key reference in one of them.

Is it possible to detect the `FOREIGN KEY (MY_KEY_ID) REFERENCES fff(ID) ON DELETE CASCADE ,` from the following script.

Note that it might not be the only occurrence of that particular text, therefore I need to find the one that occurs after `CREATE TABLE MYTABLE`.

```
CREATE TABLE MYTABLE (
  blah
  .....
  FOREIGN KEY (MY_KEY_ID) REFERENCES fff(ID) ON DELETE CASCADE ,
  FOREIGN KEY ....
)
```

**UPDATE:**

The end goal is to use a bash script to remove `ON DELETE CASCADE` from one key and add it to the next key.

Comment: Which programming language do you use?

Comment: It's not the easiest to find a line after a line with regex.  I have seen this done by reading in the script file, looping through the lines, and setting up logic to look for the sequence that you want.

Comment: What have you tried? If something works for you at least partially, we could help you fixing that. Else, it is too broad.

Comment: Yes, it's trivial with awk (sed is for s/old/new on individual lines - that's not what you're doing so you shouldn't be trying to use sed for it) but what do you want to DO with that string after you've found it - print it, modify it, delete it, or something else? [edit] your question to include the expected output given that input.

Answer (score 1):

This will find the FOREIGN KEY string after the CREATE TABLE string but now what?

```
$ awk '
    index($0,"CREATE TABLE MYTABLE") { f=1 }
    f && index($0,"FOREIGN KEY (MY_KEY_ID) REFERENCES fff(ID) ON DELETE CASCADE ,")
' file
FOREIGN KEY (MY_KEY_ID) REFERENCES fff(ID) ON DELETE CASCADE ,
```

Comment: I need to remove `ON DELETE CASCADE` from one key and add it to another key.

Comment: Sounds simple enough but [edit] your question to show a [mcve] that includes concise, testable sample input and expected output that includes these multiple keys you're talking about. Make it something we can test a potential solution against and that covers all of your sunny and rainy day cases. See [ask] if that's not clear.